# Replace Table with a fast matrix operation to create for matrices A, B the tensor (b_{ij}A) and similar questions

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors, map

I have two (nxn)-matrices A=(a_{ij}) and B=(b_{ij}) and I'd like to create the (nxnxnxn)-List

```
C=(b_{ij}*A)
```

so e.g.

```
SeedRandom["testing"]
bb = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}];
aa = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
Table[
 bb[[i, j]]*aa, {i, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 3, 1}]
```

I of course can construct it via Table[], see the above code. but it is very slow when we talk about 100x100. I guess theres a trick/possibility via Map[], but it is not

```
SeedRandom["testing"]
aa = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]
bb = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}];
cc = Map[aa, bb]
cc // MatrixForm
```

Thanks. And I guess a similar question came up, again matrices and vectors

```
vv = {1, 2, 3}
vvM = Table[
  vv[[i]] - vv[[j]], {i, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 3, 1}]
vvM // MatrixForm
```

Thanks for all the help. Just for information, I think I know Mathematica okayish but when it comes to @, @@, #, stuff like that, I am pretty new to that

Comment: I do not understand your description. Can you please be more explicit about what is the expected value of element $(i,j,k)$ of the resulting matrix $C$? From what you say, $a_{ij}\times B$ is a $n\times n$ matrix for every $(i,j)$, and so you described $C$ is a $n\times n\times n\times n$ matrix (rank-4), not rank-3.

Comment: `KroneckerProduct`?

Comment: Can you please show how you do it with `Table` and we will help you to speed it up. At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: dear Roman and Yarchik, you're totally correct, there's an error. I'll edit the posting and add a similar question, thank you in advance

Comment: `Outer[Times, bb, aa]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your need `Outer`.

```
bb = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}];
aa = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
Outer[Times, bb, aa]
```

```
vv = {1, 2, 3}
Outer[Subtract, vv, vv]
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!